# APLpy attribute error : 'module' object has no attribute 'FITSfigure'

Tags: python, python-2.7, aplpy

I have installed APLpy (version 0.9.12) & I have python 2.7.

I have a FITS image called "test.fits".

I gave following commands:

```
import aplpy
fig = aplpy.FITSfigure("test.fits")
```

Then I got this message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FITSfigure'
```

I got same message when I tried following:

```
fig = aplpy.aplpy.FITSfigure("test.fits")
```

I am new to python & APLpy.

Comment: Always include the *full traceback* in your questions. In this case I could have used that to pinpoint exactly what file you need to rename to avoid masking the module you wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
fig = aplpy.FITSfigure("test.fits")
```

is spelled wrong it has to be:

```
fig = aplpy.FITSFigure("test.fits")
```

Comment: by the way, what is difference between (1) aplpy.FITSFigure(...) and (2) aplpy.aplpy.FITSFigure(...) ? I tried both & both worked.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not familiair with Aplpy. I just looked it up for you ;)